# Android: get the photo from google place api photo response

Tags: google-places-api

I'm currently building an app that requires the photo of the selected place using google places api. I requested the photo using

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=MY_PHOTO_REF&key=API_KEY
```

My problem is how can i contain the response and display it in an ImageView. 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well looks like I got it.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=[IMAGESIZE]&photoreference=[REFERENCEKEY]&sensor=false&key=[YOURKEYHERE]
```

This will return a single image based from the `photo_reference` key.